# Youtube API insert commentThread PHP

Tags: php, youtube-api

This code doesn't work and I can't resolve it.

```
$data_channel = '{
    "snippet":
    {
        "topLevelComment":
        {
            "snippet":
            {
                "videoId":"'.$_POST['id_video'].'"
                "textOriginal":"'.$_POST['comment'].'"
            }
        }
    }
}';

echo $_COOKIE['access_token'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&access_token='.$_COOKIE['access_token']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_channel);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json')                                                                      
);        

$req_comment = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Error Message
code:'400'
Message:'Parse Error'

The authorization is done with scope force.ssl

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "Parse Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Parse Error"
 }
}
```

Request Body error returned

Comment: there's always a response body from YT even on errors, explainig the error. Probably you want to read this as well and echo/post that here

Comment: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "Parse Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Parse Error"
 }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely to generate JSON faults:

```
...
                "textOriginal":"'.$_POST['comment'].'"
            }
        }
    }
}';
```

Better would be:

```
data_channel = array(
    "snippet" => array(
            "topLevelComment" => array(
                  "snippet" => array (
                      "videoId" => $_POST['id_video'],
                      "textOriginal" => $_POST['comment']
                  )
             )
    )
);
$data_json = json_encode($data_channel, JSON_HEX_QUOT + JSON_HEX_TAG + JSON_HEX_AMP + JSON_HEX_APOS + JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

and further

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
```

since the text may contain (...is containing) invalid chars for the json.
`json_encode` deals with aht and encodes properly